# Using buffered image converting using compression

Tags: java, bufferedimage, javax.imageio

Attempting to read in a buffered bmp image and then convert with compression to jpeg.  Something is wrong with the buffered image line.  Thank you, any help is appreciated.

```
public void jpegconvert(String Fname, String Crate)
{

BufferedImage image =  ImageIO.read(Fname);

Iterator<ImageWriter> i = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpeg"); 

// Just get the first JPEG writer available 
ImageWriter jpegWriter = i.next(); 

// Set the compression quality to 0.8 
ImageWriteParam param = jpegWriter.getDefaultWriteParam(); 
param.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT); 
param.setCompressionQuality(0.8f); 

// Write the image to a file 
FileImageOutputStream out = new FileImageOutputStream(new File("newimage.jpg")); 
jpegWriter.setOutput(out); 
jpegWriter.write(null, new IIOImage(image, null, null), param); 
jpegWriter.dispose(); 
out.close();
}
}
```

**Hover error says this:**

```
no suitable method found for read(String)
    method ImageIO.read(ImageInputStream) is not applicable
      (actual argument String cannot be converted to ImageInputStream by method invocation conversion)
    method ImageIO.read(URL) is not applicable
      (actual argument String cannot be converted to URL by method invocation conversion)
    method ImageIO.read(InputStream) is not applicable
      (actual argument String cannot be converted to InputStream by method invocation conversion)
    method ImageIO.read(File) is not applicable
      (actual argument String cannot be converted to File by method invocation conversion)
```

Comment: and what is that `something` ??

Comment: no suitable method found for read(String)
    method ImageIO.read(ImageInputStream) is not applicable
  (actual argument String cannot be converted to ImageInputStream by method invocation conversion) method ImageIO.read(URL) is not applicable (actual argument String cannot be converted to URL by method invocation conversion) method ImageIO.read(InputStream) is not applicable (actual argument String cannot be converted to InputStream by method invocation conversion) method ImageIO.read(File) is not applicable (actual argument String cannot be converted to File by method invocation conversion)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

problem is with this particular code:
`ImageIO.read(Fname);`
coz `Fname` is an `String` and checking [API for read method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html) it doesnt take `String` as argument in any of its overloaded methods

this [reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/examples/LoadImageApp.java) might help you